# Run Multiple functions from an executable?

Tags: common-lisp, executable, sbcl

I build CL executables as advised in the CL cookbook. I use the ASDF method with `:entry-point`

```lisp
(asdf:defsystem #:thing
        :serial t
        :components ((:file "package")
                     (:file "thing"))
        :build-operation "program-op"
        :build-pathname "launch"
        :entry-point "thing:main")
```

I added an entry point. Which is the main function. When I open (double click) my executable, the main function runs.

As my app has grown, i have multiple stand alone "main" operations.

Is this a sign for adding a UI or can i create executables that run different operations?

Comment: It depends, maybe you could have a service that accepts different requests, or a single executable that accepts different subcommands (like "git init", "git clone"); when you have a short-lived executable (start, execute script, exit). So it depends mostly on what your goal is, if you want it to be CLI only or with a GUI, if your script could benefit from keeping track of some state (as a service) or not (as single commands); I fear this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: "when you have a short-lived executable (start, execute script, exit)" was supposed to be followed by: "all the state has to be stored externally (in the filesystem), which is not the case if you have a live service that can keep some internal state"

Comment: A standard trick (not specific to Lisp) is to dispatch on the executable name, so your 'main' function will check what the executable is called and invoke the appropriate thing.  You then just create lots of links to the same binary.

Comment: Or: call your app from the terminal and parse command-line arguments. You could then create tiny shell scripts that call the main executable with a given option.

Comment: There is also buildapp and its `--dispatched-entry` option which " was inspired by the desire to have a dozen different small utilities embedded in one big executable and called based on the binary name.". I never tried it and IDK how it works under the hood, maybe like @ignisvolens idea. https://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch on the binary name, and get the latter with `(uiop:raw-command-line-arguments)`.

Suppose I build a binary. Inside your `thing:main` function, we study how UIOP gets us the CLI args:

```lisp
  (format t "raw CLI args are: ~S~&" (uiop:raw-command-line-arguments))
  (format t "CLI args are: ~S~&" (uiop:command-line-arguments))
```

If I call `./helloapp me`, the values are:

```
raw CLI args are: ("./helloapp" "me")
CLI args are: ("me")
```

We can dispatch on the calling binary name from the `main` function.

```lisp
(defun hello (args) 
  (format t "Hello ~a!~&" (first args)))
(defun goodbye (args)
  (format t "Hello and bye ~a!~&" (first args)))

(defun main ()
  (format t "raw CLI args are: ~S~&" (uiop:raw-command-line-arguments))
  (format t "CLI args are: ~S~&" (uiop:command-line-arguments))
  (if (search "goodbye" (first (uiop:raw-command-line-arguments)) 
              :test #'equalp)
      (goodbye (uiop:command-line-arguments))
      (hello (uiop:command-line-arguments)))))
```

Creating links works:

```
$ ln -s helloapp goodbyeapp
$ ./goodbyeapp me
raw CLI args are: ("./goodbye-link" "me")
CLI args are: ("me")
var args are: ("me")
Hello and bye me!
```

*ACK: I'm building on Ignis Volens' comment and learned a trick along the way.*